Firebase multiple authentication (Google and Apple) with Flutter app
I am having a hard time understanding on how I can design a flutter screen with firebase authentication with multiple login method on the same screen. The Authentication screen (Auth_gate.dart) in my case should support:

Google Login // This one OK
Apple // This one not OK

My Firebase project as been initialised properly with Flutter.
My flutter project is well configured with firebase as per documentation.
The in-built "SignInScreen" from the firebase_auth package is doing the job well for Google sign-in And email.
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/ui/auth/integrating-your-first-screen/
Since it is working fine for Email and Google methods, I was thinking I can just add a new AppleProvider in the providers list, it will render the 'Sign in with apple' button and handle the flow like it did with Google.
I have set up my Apple developer to support the Apple Sign in method this is fine.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/apple?authuser=0#enable-apple-as-a-sign-in-provider
In the Documentation of firebase, in the flutter section I only can find these line of code, I am note sure where to put them.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/federated-auth
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

Future<UserCredential> signInWithApple() async {
  final appleProvider = AppleAuthProvider();
  if (kIsWeb) {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithPopup(appleProvider);
  } else {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithProvider(appleProvider);
  }
}

It seems the SignInScreen do not support AppleProvider() because I am getting the following error:
The element type 'AppleAuthProvider' can't be assigned to the list type 'AuthProvider<AuthListener, AuthCredential>'. (Documentation)

I have consulted the following documentation links with not much insigths:
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/ui/auth/building-a-custom-ui/
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/account-linking
Can someone explain what I am doing wrong? and how to get me back on track?
Much appreciated.
main.dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:EcoClick/screens/auth_gate.dart';
import 'package:EcoClick/screens/on_boarding.dart';
import 'package:EcoClick/screens/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'languages/deleguates.dart';
import 'languages/localizations.dart';
import 'utils/database_helper.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';

//Widget screen = const OnboardingScreen();
Widget screen = const AuthGate();

void main() {
  runZonedGuarded(() async {
    try {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
      );
      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      final bool? look = prefs.getBool('look');
      if (look == false || look == null) {
        //screen = const OnboardingScreen();
      } else {
        //screen = const PermissionWrapper();
      }
      runApp(
        Builder(
          builder: (context) =>
              Provider.value(
                  value: null,
                  builder: (context, child) => Greenprint(screen)),
        ),
      );
    }
    catch (error) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('error in main');
      }
    }
  }, (Object e, StackTrace s) {
  }, zoneSpecification: ZoneSpecification(
    print: (Zone self, ZoneDelegate parent, Zone zone, String message) {
    },
  ));
}

class Greenprint extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget screen;

  const Greenprint(this.screen, {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [ChangeNotifierProvider<MyDatabaseHelper>(
          create: (_) => MyDatabaseHelper()),],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        onGenerateTitle: (BuildContext context) =>
        MyLocalizations
            .of(context)
            .homeTitle,
        localizationsDelegates: const [
          MyLocalizationsDelegate(),
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        supportedLocales: const [
          Locale('en', ''),
          Locale('fr', ''),
        ],
        title: 'GreenPrint',
        //theme: ThemeData.dark(),
        home: screen,
      ),
    );
  }
}

auth_gate.dart
import 'package:EcoClick/screens/camera_widget.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' hide EmailAuthProvider;
import 'package:firebase_ui_auth/firebase_ui_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_ui_oauth_google/firebase_ui_oauth_google.dart'; // new
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple.dart';


class AuthGate extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthGate({super.key});

  AppleAuthProvider test(){
    var appleProvider = AppleAuthProvider();
    appleProvider.addScope('email');
    appleProvider.setCustomParameters({
      'locale': 'fr',
    });

    FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithPopup(appleProvider);
    return appleProvider;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<User?>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return SignInScreen(
            providers: [
              EmailAuthProvider(),
              GoogleProvider(clientId: "0000000.apps.googleusercontent.com"),  //OK
              AppleAuthProvider() // Gives error: The element type 'AppleAuthProvider' can't be assigned to the list type 'AuthProvider<AuthListener, AuthCredential>'. (Documentation)

             ],
            headerBuilder: (context, constraints, shrinkOffset) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 1,
                  child: Image.asset('images/icon/icon.png'),
                ),
              );
            },
            subtitleBuilder: (context, action) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                child: action == AuthAction.signIn
                    ? const Text('Welcome to FlutterFire, please sign in!')
                    : const Text('Welcome to Flutterfire, please sign up!'),
              );
            },

            footerBuilder: (context, action) {
              return const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                child: Text(
                  'By signing in, you agree to our terms and conditions.',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                ),
              );
            },
            sideBuilder: (context, shrinkOffset) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 1,
                  child: Image.asset('flutterfire_300x.png'),
                ),
              );
            },

          );
        }

        return const CameraScreen();
      },
    );
  }
}


Well, kind of answering my own question!
This helped a lot to understand.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMS4TSFwml8&t=902s&ab_channel=ShivamGupta
https://github.com/shivam22rkl/Google-Apple-SignIn/tree/main
Hope it helps,
Cheers

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
